# how about the memory management of block in this code

Tags: ios, objective-c, block

this is the code:

```
blk_t blk;
 {

    id array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    blk = ^(id obj) {
        [array addObject:obj];
        NSLog(@"array count = %ld", [array count]);
    };
 }
blk([[NSObject alloc] init]);
blk([[NSObject alloc] init]);
blk([[NSObject alloc] init]);
```

it is said the application will be terminated because the block do not copy from stack to heap and the automatic variable 'array' has be released and disposed of,but in my test it works without terminated.what is the issue? and i am interesting in how memory management work in this code,who can explain it?

Comment: by the way,the test environment is under the ARC.

Answer (score 0):

A block literal like

```
^(id obj) { ... }
```

is only valid within its enclosing scope. You leave the enclosing scope immediately after assigning the literal to blk, and it becomes invalid.

Don't use it inside a scope (remove the { } ) or use the copy method.

BTW. Assigning a mutable array to a variable of type id is awful style and will catch you out badly at some point.

Comment: this is just a test code for me to understand the memory management of block.and you mean that the blk is invalid,do that mean the Block is NSConcreteStackBlock type? so it have released when leave the enclosing scope? i think so but why it works with no problem? is that the ARC'tricky?